# basic angular form validation not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

Template:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <p>Add products here</p>
        <form name="addProductForm" data-ng-submit="addProduct(addProductForm.$valid)" novalidate>
            <label for="productName">Name</label>
            <input name="productName" type="text" placeholder="name" data-ng-model="product.name" required="" />
            <p ng-show="addProductForm.name.$valid" >Wrong Name</p>
            <p ng-show="addProductForm.name.$invalid" >Write Name</p>
            <label for="productName">Type</label>
            <input name="productName" type="text" placeholder="name" data-ng-model="product.type" required="" />
            <input type="submit" data-ng-disabled="addProductForm.$invalid" class="btn" value="Add" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have added two p tags one with valid and other with invalid but both of them are not showing up.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: look if you got any errors in F12 (developer tools) on youre browser. Look at console tab

Comment: Where are you declaring your controller (ng-controller) and your app (ng-app) in your html?

Comment: there is no error in the console. controller and app is well defined everything else is working

Comment: https://github.com/sarabs3/shapne link of the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your "name" property of your inputs.

```
<p ng-show="addProductForm.productName.$invalid" >Wrong Name</p>
<p ng-show="addProductForm.productType.$invalid" >Write Name</p>


<input name="productType" type="text" data-ng-model="product.type" required="" />
<input name="productName" type="text" placeholder="name" data-ng-model="product.name" required="" />
```

The "name" property has to match whatever you are evaluating in the condition.

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rskhLcnz/

Comment: yes i have changed the name of the field to match the name of the model and it is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use **ngMessages** instead of **ngShow** and remember the field names

```
    <form name="myForm" ng-init="formData = {}">
      <input name="productName" type="text" ng-model="formData.productName" placeholder="Product name" required>
      <div ng-messages="myForm.productName.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
      </div>
      <input name="productType" type="text" ng-model="formData.productType" placeholder="Product type" required>
      <div ng-messages="myForm.productType.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" class="btn" value="Add" />
    </form>
    <pre>{{formData}}</pre>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/grishkovelli/de5ooLco/2/)

[AngularJS Form Validation with ngMessages](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages%20%22%22)